# Where are all of the secrets in 'The Shores of Hell'?

Tags: doom

I've finished playing through Episode 1 (Knee Deep in the Dead) of The Ultimate Doom whilst finding all of the secret areas, collecting all of the items and killing all the things.

I've played through Episode 2 (The Shores of Hell) but not succeeded in finding all of the secret areas.

Like each of the DOOM episodes, there are nine levels - eight normal levels and one secret level in each - but I didn't find the entrance to the secret level in the second episode.

The nine levels in 'The Shores of Hell' are;

- E2 M1: Deimos Anomaly
- E2 M2: Containment Area
- E2 M3: Refinery
- E2 M4: Deimos Lab
- E2 M5: Command Center
- E2 M6: Halls of the Damned
- E2 M7: Spawning Vats
- E2 M8: Tower of Babel
- E2 M9: ??? (Secret Level)

[image: The Shores of Hell]

Where are all of the secrets in The Ultimate DOOM Episode 2 - 'The Shores of Hell'?

Comment: There are 52 secrets in total in Shores of Hell, listing them all would require a very very long answer. Could you be more level-specific? Additionally this information is currently available at http://doom.wikia.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a website called Classic Doom. It has information about maps and secrets for the PC and console versions ofUltimate Doom and Doom 2, as well as Master Levels, Final Doom and even Doom 64.

here's the link: http://www.classicdoom.com/

As for getting to the secret level, In E2M5, there should be a switch in one of the rooms that lifts up the floor into stairs and there should be a secret teleporter that should lead you into the secret exit.

I don't think that E2M8 has any secrets in the level, I believe, but I could be wrong.