# Where can I find all of the secret areas in 'Inferno'?

Tags: doom

I purchased DOOM 3 BFG edition, which includes The Ultimate DOOM, DOOM2, and DOOM3.

I've played the first two episodes (Knee-Deep In The Dead and The Shores of Hell) already, and I'm starting out on the third episode - Inferno.

Like each of the DOOM episodes, there are nine levels - eight normal levels and one secret level in each - I haven't had any success in finding the secret levels in any episode yet, although I managed to clear the first episode with 100% of all secrets and I'll be [replaying the second episode soon to get 100% on this also](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96826/27134), with any luck.

The nine levels in 'Inferno' are;

- E3 M1: Hell Keep
- E3 M2: Slough of Despair
- E3 M3: Pandemonium
- E3 M4: House of Pain
- E3 M5: Unholy Cathedral
- E3 M6: Mt. Erebus
- E3 M7: Limbo
- E3 M8: Dis
- E3 M9: ??? (Secret Level)

[image: The Shores of Hell]

Where are all of the secrets in The Ultimate DOOM Episode 3 - 'Inferno'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a site called [Classic Doom](http://classicdoom.com/maps/d1secs/d1.htm#e3m1) that is super awesome to include maps with flashing hidden areas! I'll be posting a screenshot later tonight to help out if you don't want to make the jump.

**Episode 3 Mission 1:**

> [image: E3M1]

**Episode 3 Mission 2:**

> [image: E3M2]